# How to remove uipasteboard item after once it was pasted in some other app

Tags: ios

Here my requirement is to remove the UIPasteboard item when once it was pasted in some other app.

how i am copying string to UIPasteboard is

```
UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pb setString:@”Hello Pastebot!”];
```

Now i want to remove this text from UIPasteboard once it was copied in some other app.

Can any one help me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not what user expects. User copies and keeps on pasting on different applications. He will feel strange isn't it?

Comment: Here my requirement should copy for only once

Comment: because i'm copying password to UIPasteboard

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to fulfill your requirement, but maybe you can reach your goal (keeping the transfered password as secret as possible) by autoremoving it shortly after transfer.

Just set a timer, let's say for 30 seconds at the moment the password is placed into the general pasteboard and when the timer fires clear the pasteboards content.

**[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setString:@""];**

Of course you should inform your users about this 'special behaviour' of your app (and maybe make it optional or configuarable in your app settings).